# What is the photo_reference field in the Places API?

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api

I understand most of the fields in the Places API, but I don't understand how to interpret the `photo_reference` field in the JSON.

Here is the Snapshot of the JSON:
[click to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITt86.png)

Comment: I guess checking the documentation or doing a web search wasn't an option?

Comment: @Robert yes ofc it was, but the documentation does not seem to be useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlacePhoto which can be used to access the photos of the place https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/photos.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I get That, I Tried using JSONArray but the problem is instead of getting the photo_reference I am getting something else and I am not sure what it is